# Оператор where для внутреннего столбца Cassandra CQL

Tags: sql, nosql, cassandra

в колонке data имеются другая таблица. Я могу как то отсортировать по внутренней таблице

select data from smart.rejectevent2 where data.eventsource = '3248781154' allow filtering;

не работает. На скринах структура таблицы. 9 обычных колон и data в которой свои колонки

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1):

В Cassandra сортировка происходит только по колонке которая объявлена как clustering column, и это происходит только внутри раздела (partition). Обычно для таких вещей надо использовать что-то типа Spark SQL (например, через [Spark Thrift Server](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-distributed-sql-engine.html)).